# Angular hide flexslider on root url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flexslider

So, I want to `ng-hide` a `div` which has `flexslider` in it on `root`. The problem is that the `images` won't load after going to another path.

My `index.html` looks like:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#/">Root</a></li>           <!-- don't show slider -->
  <li><a href="#/first">First</a></li>     <!-- show slider -->
  <li><a href="#/second">Second</a></li>   <!-- show slider -->
</ul>

<div ng-controller="SliderController">
  <div ng-include="'slider.html'" ng-hide="currentPath === '/'"></div>
</div>

<div ng-view></div>
```

And `app.js`:

```
app.controller('SliderController', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location){ 
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
        $scope.currentPath = $location.path();
    });
}]);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g94FrJ9M1XfCErGVlpdA)

When you start the plunker, it shows you the `index.html`- without `flexslider`, which is good:

[image: Root view]

---

And now when you click on *first* or *second* link, the template view changes and the `first.html/second.html` template loads, and it should also show the *flexslider*, which doesn't. But it shows the *flexslider styles* (notice the box shadow).

[image: First view]

But if you leave it on the `first/second` view, and switch tab and return (in browser), it shows the images.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: initial suggestion: Whenever you're going to manipulate the DOM in anyway, use a directive.  So the initialization of your flexslider should be within a directive.

Comment: @MichaelLynch I tried it, but it didn't help. Maybe I was doing something wrong. Can you give it a try in the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g94FrJ9M1XfCErGVlpdA)?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you manipulate the DOM in any manner you should do so via a Directive and not within a controller or pure Javascript.

For this issue in particular (using Angular with FlexSlider) I would suggest looking at the directive someone made to make these work nicely with each other.

https://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider

Comment: I agree that this solve the image problem, but the slider now doesn't work. [If you see in the image](http://s28.postimg.org/ly1uzksnx/image.png), `div.flex-viewport` should be **inside** `div.flexslider`, not outside it.

Comment: I saw that directive. I will use it as a last resort. I believe the solution to my problem is something simple so I'm not just giving up yet :)

Comment: Well from my last answer (using the directive).  Perhaps change the start param to what this directive has (https://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider/blob/master/angular-flexslider.js#L149-L161).  Also not sure why they have a timeout when starting flexslider, but that could be another thing to try.